# MongoDB Server has authorization schema version 3, but found a schema version 1 user

Tags: mongodb

Trying to restore a production MongoDB onto a dev MongoDB and getting this error

```
assertion: 17408 Server has authorization schema version 3, 
but found a schema version 1 user: { _id: ObjectId('5256c667c8bf4cc093fa9794'), 
user: "adminuser", userSource: "mongoUsers", roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase",
 "dbAdminAnyDatabase", "clusterAdmin", "readWriteAnyDatabase" ] }
```

Production Server is sharded and using version 2.6.3

Dev Server is a 2.6.3 and using version 2.6.3

Client being used to restore is version 2.6.1 (maybe this is the problem?)

Only the user databases are copied, the config, admin and users databases are not restored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved**

Upgrading to mongo shell 2.6.3 resolved the issue.

Comment: May I know how you upgrade the mongo client?